# Implementing the Binary Tree in C

Tags: c, binary-tree

I am trying to implement the Binary tree in C.Firstly inserting the values and then traversing them into the Preorder.But when i call the function preorder() then it's giving me infinite loop with only last value inserted.
I am using following code:

```
struct node* insert(struct node *root,int num);

void preorder(struct node *root);

struct node *root=NULL;

int count=1;

struct node {

    struct node *lchild;
    struct node *rchild; 
int data;
};

int main(){

    root=insert(root,1);
//root=insert(root,2);
preorder(root); 
return;
}

struct node* insert(struct node *root,int num){//insert a node into tree

   //struct node *q;
if(root==NULL)
{
    root=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node)); 
    root->data=num;
    root->lchild=NULL;
    root->rchild=NULL;
    //root=q;
    count++;
}
else{
    if(count % 2==0){
        root->lchild=insert(root->lchild,num);
    }
    else{
        root->rchild=insert(root->rchild,num);
    }
}
return(root);
}

void preorder(struct node *root){

    while(root!=NULL){
    printf("%d\t",root->data);
    preorder(root->lchild);
    preorder(root->rchild);     
}
}
```

here i am inserting only 1 value initially but the bug occurs.So in insert() there should not be any mistake,something correction should be done in preorder() or main()..what it can be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what `preorder()` should do, but this line causes the endless loop:

```
 while(root!=NULL){
```

I guess you meant to write `if` not `while`

Answer (score 2):

You need an if statement not a while statement in your preorder function.

```
while(root!=NULL){ //This is causing the infinite loop
```

In the loop body, you do not change the root pointer at any point so, if the condition is ever  true, which it is for the root element, it will never come out of the loop.

It should instead be :

```
if(root!=NULL){
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write `if` rather than `while` so that the recursive loop had an base condition and it ends somewhere.

In your code instead of writing `if(root!=NULL)` write `while(root!=NULL)`